# How can I use javac to cross compile my old tests to be compatible with java 8?

Tags: java, testing, java-8, java-7, cross-compiling

I work for a company that is currently developing a server software and it is my job to run automated tests for this software. The newest version of the server is built using Java 8, and this is causing problems because our old testing framework is made to accommodate Java 7. We use the TestNG plugin for java to run all our tests, but as far as I can tell, every single version of TestNG is compiled with java 7, so if I compile the tests with java 8, the plugin will throw a major.minor unsupported 52.0 error if I try to run them with the plugin. On the other hand, compiling the tests with Java 7 causes the same error to occur when the tests try to send requests to the server.

How can I cross-compile these tests so that they work with both TestNG and the server? The interaction works like: TestNG calls the tests, and then the tests call the server.

I've read up on this a little and I think I need something like:

javac -source 1.7 -target 1.8 projectName

Is this a viable approach?

Comment: If you need your compiled classes to work with Java 7, use `-target 1.7`.

Comment: TestNG supports Java 7 *or higher*, so it should work. Of course if you use `-target 1.8`, you'll need a 1.8 JVM to run your tests. Concerning the sending of requests to the server, we will need more context to understand how those requests could be affected by the target or JVM version.

Comment: I tried -target 1.7 already. It made the tests compatible with the TestNG plugin, but now they are incompatible with the server itself. I can't give away too many details @Didier L (proprietary knowledge and whatnot) but the server has many class files (compiled with java8) and the tests call functions that are in those class files to interact with the server.

Comment: Classes compiled with `-target 1.7` should run on a 1.8 JVM without issues, be it TestNG or your own code. If you don't give more details I'm afraid nobody can help. Like this we don't even know how you are running TestNG, nor which app server you are running. Also, you should choose whether you would prefer to run your tests on a 1.7 or 1.8 JVM, and focus on having that working. I would go for a 1.8 if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I faced the same issue in one of my projects. javac -source 1.7 -target 1.8 projectName worked fine for me